# Relation between bases while changing into a SNP

Tags: snp

Is there any relation or influence among the bases (A, C, G, T) while they are converted into a `snp`? Such as, is `A` converted into `T`, similar to converted into `C` or `G`? Or is this all random and no way to evaluate?

Comment: Interesting question. You can start here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1790724/ and here: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v505/n7485/full/nature12861.html I may convert this into answer later, time allowing.